# R: GEOCODE()- Returns short coordinates

Tags: r, geocoding, geocode

I have a task to return a coordinates (lon, lat) from R using GEOCODE() function.
Everything went smooth with API and installing packages and so on.

However, when testing the coordinates I noticed that R returned short (lon, lat)
For example for 'LV-2114' R returned short versions:

```
> geocode("LV-2114", output = "latlon", "latlona", source="google", 
       full_results = TRUE, return_type = 'geographies',method = 'census')

#> A tibble: 1 x 2 
#>    lon   lat  
#>    23.9  56.8
```

For the "LV-2114" the lon, lat should be (23.94453,56.79256). And the same goes with other places I input.

I'm pretty sure it is some mistake I made.
How can I return long coordinates?

Comment: I think it's just the tibble printing that does that. can you try `df$lon` and check the output

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk Thank  you for your reply. Do you mean in one single line ?geocode("LV-2114",df$lon). If yes, then it returned error "Error in df$lon : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable". Or do you mean something else?

Comment: what I mean is `df <- goecode(.......)` then `df$lon`

Comment: And it's definitely the tibble rounding

Comment: if you want them into a vector just write `as.data.frame(df)[1, , drop=T]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *error* you're experiencing is just the default behavior of print.tibble that rounds numeric values.

```r
df <- geocode("LV-2114", output = "latlon", "latlona", source="google", 
       full_results = TRUE, return_type = 'geographies',method = 'census')

as.data.frame(df)[,, drop=T]
#> $lon
#> [1] 23.94453
#> 
#> $lat
#> [1] 56.79256
# or
as.matrix(df)

#>           lon      lat
#> [1,] 23.94453 56.79256
#> [2,] 23.94453  2.00000
```

when you're gonna use the values inside the tibble in calculation it will use the non rounded values, only when printing does the values get rounded.